# Drupal 7, displaying page custom field with handling null exceptions

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

```
 <?php if ($content['field_banner']): ?>
            <div class="proj"><?php print render($content['field_banner']) ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

My if condition is not working, if the page doesn't have banner, i am getting an error:
Notice: Undefined index: field_banner in include() (line 28 of node.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little isset() can make the difference.

```
<?php if (isset($content['field_banner'])): ?>
```